# Create a List out of an tuple array

Tags: python-2.7

I am scripting in Python2.7.I have an array like `k = ((12,12.356,40.365),(458,12.2258,42.69))` and I want to create a list out of the first element of each subset like:

```
for i in K:
   l = k[i][0]
```

While I have encountered the error `"tuple indices must be integers, not tuple".`
Would you please let me know how can I come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `k` tuple item by tuple like `k[(12,12.356,40.365)][0]`, while an item of ordered sequence should be accessed by its position/index (for ex. `k[0][0]`).

Use list comprehension to get *a list out of the first element of each subset*:

```
k = ((12,12.356,40.365),(458,12.2258,42.69))
result = [t[0] for t in k]
print(result)
```

The outtut:

```
[12, 458]
```